# Basic question about partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I recently started reading Peter Olver’s “Introduction to partial differential equations”. At the start of the book is an exercise that is difficult. The preceding text was about solving very basic pdes, $u_t=c$ and other questions of similar form, but then came the question $u_x+tu=0$ , the question confused me, and I still struggle with using scalars as coefficients of the functions. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember how to solve your linear first order ODEs?

Comment: I remember the processes to solve them faintly, but the assistance the book provides and my prior knowledge (built up mostly by khanacademy) didn’t provide me enough clarity to solve the PDE

Comment: I don't remember this exercise in this book, can you point out exactly where it is?

Answer (score 0):

By inspection you can see that $$e^{-tx},$$ is a solution. What can you say about the general solution?